# Print out all numbers 1 - 1000 except those divisible by 100

Tags: ruby, loops, conditional-statements

My exercise wants all numbers 1 - 1000 returned except those divisible by 100.

```
n = 1
1000.times do
  if n % 1 == 0
    if n % 100 == 0
      if n % 400 == 0
        p n
      else
      end
    else
      p n
    end
  else
  end
  n = n + 1
end
```

Numbers 400 and 800 are still printing. Need help understanding why this isn't working.

Comment: Well your code clearly says that numbers evenly divisible by 400 (which includes 400 and 800) SHOULD be printed.... Why is the line `if n % 400 == 0` even there to begin with?

Comment: You can print the numbers 1 to 10 except those divisible by 2 using `(1..10).each { |n| p n unless n % 2 == 0 }`. Use this as a template.

Comment: could you please clarify if the filtered numbers should be returned as an array or printed as they're processed?

Comment: Thanks, for responding and your help. It's suppose to be printed as they're processed

Comment: Okay. I think I got it. Thanks to you. I removed 400. Thank you. I just needed to understand why the 400 was included.

Comment: Well, it's YOUR program, isn't it? So why did you include it in the first place???

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Integer#times` and keeping track of `n` yourself, consider using [`Range#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-each) like so:

```
(1..1000).each do |n|
  puts n if n % 100 != 0
end
```

You can also pass a block to [`Integer#times`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times), but you should be aware that `n` will start at `0` and go up to `Integer - 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So this is from a beginner Ruby exercise. so, we haven't been introduced to your suggested process. We are to run the program as is.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:
Create a range of numbers between 1 and 1000 and filter out those divisible by 100.

```
puts [*1..1000].reject{|n| n % 100 == 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two *hints* here:

- You do *not* need to introduce a new variable for this.  You can use the one provided to you by the range.

  ```
  1000.times do |i|
    # code
  end
  ```
- In Ruby specifically, the `unless` keyword works as a negative `if`.  Think about this sentence: "Unless the variable I'm looking at is divisible by zero, I want to print it."  You can use that to assist.  You do *not* need more than one condition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I believe I understand the code better and removed the 400 and its corresponding else/end. I believe this is the correct answer. Thanks for your help guys. Just started learning Ruby.

```
n = 1

1000.times do
 if n % 1 == 0 
  if n % 100 == 0
          else
              p n
          end
        else
        end
n = n + 1 
end
```